# Netsuite: Send Reminder Emails to Sales based on 7 day out quote date

Tags: netsuite

Based on an entered quote date, I need an email reminder to follow up sent to the assigned sales team member 7 days after quote date. I can make the saved search but Im not sure how to get it to the correct person on the correct days.

Comment: I would advise to handle it within a `Scheduled` script (or a Map/Reduce). You need some scripting knowledge though. Getting into scripting will allow you to solve a lot of issues in a more flexible way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're sending it to the sales rep on the quote, use the **Email** tab and select **Recipients from Results** subtab. In the **Recipients** field, select **Sales Rep**

[image: Sales Rep]

Then goto the **Schedule** subtab and set how often you would like the email to go out.  Netsuite will automatically send out one email per sales rep value, on the defined schedule.

Note that if you've defined your criteria to select all quotes at or over 7 days old, then the rep will get a reminder every time the email is scheduled to send.